# Get row numbers for MySQL query, then filter where row number between values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have seen some examples on Stack Oveflow of a query I needed to retrieve row numbers for a MySQL query. What I want to do is expand on that a little to allow me to then restrict the set of results where the row number is between two values. This is allow to paginate my results table.

The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT l.ID, l.Name, l.Value, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM $table
  ORDER BY Name ASC
) l
JOIN (
  SELECT @curRow := 0
) r
WHERE row_number BETWEEN 1 AND 3
```

This query works up until the point where I add the WHERE clause at the end, and gives me the error unknown column row_number. I thought it might be because I named the table l, so tried it with WHERE l.row_number BETWEEN, but gives me the same problem.

Can someone suggest how I can restrict the query where the row number is between two values, or suggest an alternate query that would serve the same purpose?

Comment: Use start and end limit.

Comment: WHERE row_number>=1 AND row_number<=3

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it is a bit ugly but here is what I have that works:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT l.ID, l.Name, l.Value, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number 
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM $table 
        ORDER BY Name ASC
    ) l 
    JOIN (
        SELECT @curRow := 0
    ) r
) t 
WHERE row_number BETWEEN $start AND $end
```

So I am selecting all fields from the table, ordered by name. I am then getting a subset of fields from that query, and getting the row number for each row returned. I am then doing a third SELECT query on that set of results to get rows where the row_number is between two values. I can then get a total count of rows returned by simply removing the outer most SELECT statement.

Like I said, ugly, but functional. If anyone can suggest a way to tidy this, that would be great.

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT * FROM your_table LIMIT 5, 5`

This will show records 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10

Comment: This will work well, but it prevents me from doing a mysql_num_rows, as it will always return the same limit.

Comment: make 2 queries one for getting the total records and the other for getting specific records for that page. That is what done in all pagination scripts.

Comment: Having said that, I could always do another identical query and just drop the limit. That would then give me the total number of rows.

Comment: yeah you have to do ths. :)

Comment: The problem is, if I use the LIMIT method rather than my original row_number query, I am not sure how to tell I have made it to the end of my set of results. What I wanted to do, was get the total rows in the table, and say, if this record has a row number equal to the total rows, hide the next page button

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much!